# Titanium appcelerator window add multiple url

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

In titanium appcelerator we can add single external js file to our window as follow

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url:'myfile.js'
})
```

Can we add multiple js file to window?

Comment: Why you want multiple js file ?

Comment: I just want to know is it possible?

Comment: For my info No ! 
But if you want you can use `Alloy` instead classic and you can use `Rquire` tag

Comment: Okey..thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2):

The `url` property of Ti.UI.Window was deprecated long ago, maybe 2 years ago. It was a terrible implementation back in the day. You should not be using it.

If you won't want to use the Alloy framework, you should be creating windows as CommonJS modules where you export a window reference or a method to open the window. There are examples of this in the guides.